# How does multiplicative binary search algorithm work?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I want how many time complexity of my program. In my opinion it have a O(log n)

```
def multiplicative_binary_search(arr, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = int(math.sqrt(left * right))
        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid - 1
    
    return -1
```

I tried to use chatgpt but I have a doubt using it

Comment: You have a very strange algorithm. I'm not sure on complexity, but >O(log n) and <O(n)

Comment: Looks O(logn) to me.

Comment: The complexity is O(lg n) as long as you are not producing a *constant*-sized left- or right half. `m` can be the arithmetic mean, the geometric mean, or any constant-sized *fraction* of the whole array, as long as it is not a constant itself.

Answer (score 0):

I just printed out some worst case times:

```python
import math

def t(n):
    count=0
    x=0
    while(x<n):
        count+=1
        x=max(int(math.sqrt(x*n)),x+1)
    return count

print(t(10))
print(t(100))
print(t(1000))
print(t(10000))
print(t(100000))
print(t(1000000))
print(t(10000000))
print(t(100000000))
```

It's O(log N), but worse than a binary search:

```
7
12
16
20
24
27
31
34
```